Does my PC support Ubuntu 24.04 LTS?
I tried to install Ubuntu 24.04 (dual boot). While booting up the PC gspca_gl860:ctrl transfer failed-110 message showed up.
After that Ubuntu 24.04 installation window opened, at final stage a message popped up saying system program problem detected.
My PC specification:

AMD Sempron 145 Processor 2.80 ghz,
Manufacturor- ASUSTeK Computer INC [M4N68TMV2]
4GB RAM,
Display driver: NVIDIA GeForce 7025/ NVIDIA nForce 630a

Aug 02 20:51:46 ubuntu subiquity_event.4859[4859]: subiquity/load_cloud_config/extract_autoinstall: 
Aug 02 20:51:51 ubuntu subiquity_event.4859[4859]: subiquity/load_cloud_config/extract_autoinstall: 
Aug 02 20:51:52 ubuntu subiquity_event.4859[4859]: subiquity/Early/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Aug 02 20:51:52 ubuntu subiquity_event.4859[4859]: subiquity/Early/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Aug 02 20:51:52 ubuntu subiquity_event.4859[4859]: subiquity/Reporting/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Aug 02 20:51:52 ubuntu subiquity_event.4859[4859]: subiquity/Reporting/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Aug 02 20:51:52 ubuntu subiquity_event.4859[4859]: subiquity/Error/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Aug 02 20:51:52 ubuntu subiquity_event.4859[4859]: subiquity/Error/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Aug 02 20:51:52 ubuntu subiquity_event.4859[4859]: subiquity/Userdata/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Aug 02 20:51:52 ubuntu subiquity_event.4859[4859]: subiquity/Userdata/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Aug 02 20:51:52 ubuntu subiquity_event.4859[4859]: subiquity/Package/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Aug 02 20:51:52 ubuntu subiquity_event.4859[4859]: subiquity/Package/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Aug 02 20:51:52 ubuntu subiquity_event.4859[4859]: subiquity/Debconf/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Aug 02 20:51:52 ubuntu subiquity_event.4859[4859]: subiquity/Debconf/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Aug 02 20:51:52 ubuntu subiquity_event.4859[4859]: subiquity/Kernel/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Aug 02 20:51:52 ubuntu subiquity_event.4859[4859]: subiquity/Kernel/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Aug 02 20:51:52 ubuntu subiquity_event.4859[4859]: subiquity/Zdev/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Aug 02 20:51:52 ubuntu subiquity_event.4859[4859]: subiquity/Zdev/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Aug 02 20:51:52 ubuntu subiquity_event.4859[4859]: subiquity/Ad/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Aug 02 20:51:52 ubuntu subiquity_event.4859[4859]: subiquity/Ad/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Aug 02 20:51:52 ubuntu subiquity_event.4859[4859]: subiquity/Late/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Aug 02 20:51:52 ubuntu subiquity_event.4859[4859]: subiquity/Late/apply_autoinstall_config: 
Aug 02 20:53:04 ubuntu subiquity_event.4859[4859]: subiquity/Ad/has_support_GET: 
Aug 02 21:25:46 ubuntu subiquity_event.4859[4859]: subiquity/Ad/has_support_GET: 


More information needed, please edit the question: 1. How was the Ubuntu 24.04 media made? Rufus? Ventoy? Other? 2. Which version: Desktop from https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop, Server, etc. 3. Does the issue occur when trying Ubuntu, before installing? 4. Which kernel version? Note bug in kernel before 6.9!  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1513277/keyboard-problem-on-new-asus-vivobook-pro-15-n6506mv-in-ubuntu-24-04

Nowhere in your question you explicitly say whether or not the installed system booted in the end, irrespective of the "system program problem detected" that could be about anything but rarely "fatal" or the error/warning message at the start also not "fatal".
Generally speaking, your old computer should still support standard Ubuntu but barely. Standard Ubuntu (with Gnome DE) is NOT recommended for such old machines.
Prefer Lubuntu, a much lighter Ubuntu official derivative ("flavor") and keep in mind you won't be using Nvidia proprietary drivers. As such, adjust your expectations accordingly.

That sounds like an error with a webcam driver. gspca_gl860 is the kernel driver for the Genesys Logic GL860 webcam. If you actually have that webcam, disconnect it. If you don't have that, do a check on the install media to make sure it isn't corrupted.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
